# MongoDB add personal userDetails to mongoDB user

Tags: database, mongodb, authentication, settings

I want to create a mongoDB database of mongoDb user details , where each MongoDb user apart from admin could only read  his assigned entry of user details from a collection. All users with this role could only read data entry where value in field "entryOwner" is equal to his userId. Is it possible to achieve this via a single custom user-role or should I settle for inefficient solution of single entry collections for each user which only he can access?

I tried searching whether it is possible to achieve this in order to try these uses for mongoDB. First being a bit safer authentification between different apps (instead of LDAP server) which share the same databases. Second being to store application settings of different apps which share all of their data fields, but are to be accessed only by the user of the specific application. Third being the possibility to use this for managing a single mongodb which would manage dbs for multiple separate apps and projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can create [Collection-Level Access Control](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/core/collection-level-access-control/) in MongoDB to control access to certain *collections* at the database level. It does not allow for Document-Level control in the way that SQL databases allow Row-Level Security.

It is also possible to implement the control you are describing through your API using middleware. You would simply decode whatever token or headers are passed and if the userId does not equal "entryOwner", then access to that query is denied.

Not sure what language your API is written in, but if I were to do it in express.js it would look something like this:

```
//  User details route
//  GET /api/details/:id

const auth = require('./where/your/auth/logic/lives.js');
const project = require('protect.js');

router.get('/:id', auth, protect('user', 'admin'), async(req, res, next) => {
  try{
    const userDetails = await Details.findById(req.params.id);

    if (!userDetails) {
      return next(
        new ErrorResponse(`No details with the id of ${req.params.id}`, 404)
      );
    }

    // Make sure details belongs to user or is admin

    if (userDetails.entryOwner.toString() !== req.user.userId && req.user.role 
     !== 'admin') {
      return next(new ErrorResponse(`Not authorized to view details`, 401));
    }

    res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      userDetails
    });
  } catch(err){
     // handle error
  }
});
```

```
// protect.js
// Middleware which checks route before querying data

exports.protect = (...roles) => {
 return (req, res, next) => {
  if (!roles.includes(req.user.role)) {
   return next(
    new ErrorResponse(
     `User role ${req.user.role} is not authorized to access this route`,
      403
     )
   );
  }
  next();
 };
};
```